NullPointerException in autowired datasource after adding method level security annotation
I have a class using an autowired datasource. After I added a @PreAuthorize("hasRole") annotation to one of the methods in the class, the application throws a NPE when using the datasource for the first time.

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javax.sql.DataSource.getConnection()" because "this.dataSource" is null

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/Parent")

public class ParentController {
    
    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(ParentController.class);
    
    @Autowired DataSource dataSource;
    @Autowired UserManager userManager;
    @Autowired EmailService mailService;

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('COORDINATOR')")
    @PostMapping("/create")
    private String createParent(final Parent inParent, HttpServletResponse response) {   

If I remove the @PreAuthorize annotation, everything works, no NPE. Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Make the method public instead of private.

Ah.. thanks. Seems obvious now :-) So, just to be clear, it is only the methods with GET or POST mappings that need to be public when using the @PreAuthorize annotations? ie. the internal methods (unmapped) can still be private?

No all methods that need AOP need to be public. Spring AOP by default uses proxies (dynamically created classes) and behavior is added by overriding methods, a private method cannot be overridden, just like a final method. I explain that (and more here -> https://deinum.biz/2020-07-03-Autowired-Field-Null/) (option 4 is yours :) ).

Hmm, ok. It may be a design issue with my class then. I have mapped methods as well as  unmapped methods in the same RestController class. But I don't seem to get the NPE when calling the unmapped methods, even if they have the @PreAuthorize annotations.

It has nothing to do with the mapped methods it has to do with @PreAuthorize which generates the proxy not the request mapping methods. If you are calling those unmapped methods and they are private you are probaly calling them from public methods instead of directly. Not posing an issue as those are then called on the actual objct (but the @PreAuthorize is now useless as it is not proxied nor will that even work for internal method calls).

Yes, the private un-mapped methods are always called from the (now public) mapped methods.

When using @PreAuthorize or other means that require Spring AOP make sure you don't place them on private or final methods. Those methods won't be proxied and thus will be invoked on the proxied object (which will not have the dependencies injected).
This is a problem in this case as the request handling method is being called directly and thus invoked on the proxy instead of the wrapped object.
To fix make the method public instead of private.
More information is in this blogpost written by me (as you aren't the first and probably not the last to run into this).
